# how to retrieve table values using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

how to retrieve email value when we click on `<a>` tag "Add as friend" and also when we get email value then change `<a>` tag "Add as friend" to "Friend request sent" ?

sorry.... for my bad english.

**find-friends.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Find Friends</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h4><a href="php/logout.php">Log Out</a> </h4>

    <table class="details" align="center">  
    </table>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/find-friends.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**find-friends.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('php/find-friends.php', function( data ) {

        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            var tr=$('<tr></tr>');
            $.each(value, function(key, val) {

                if (key === 'name') {
                    // $('#name').append('Name:'+ ' ' + val);
                    $('<td>'+"Name : "+val+ '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' +'</td>').appendTo(tr);
                }

                if (key === 'mobile') {
                    $('<td>'+"Mobile : "+val+ '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' +'</td>').appendTo(tr);
                }

                if (key === 'email') {
                    $('<td>'+"Email : "+val+'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+'</td>').appendTo(tr);
                    // $('<td>'+'<a href=# class=link>'+'Add as Friend'+'</a>'+'</td>').appendTo(tr);
                    $('<tr><td>'+'<a href="#" class="link">'+"Add as Friends"+'</a>'+'</td>').appendTo(tr);
                }
            });
            tr.appendTo('.details');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be better to use CSS padding instead of all those `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the email as a `data` attribute to the link:

```
if (key === 'email') {
    $('<td>'+"Email : "+val+'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+'</td>').appendTo(tr);
    // $('<td>'+'<a href=# class=link>'+'Add as Friend'+'</a>'+'</td>').appendTo(tr);
    $('<tr><td>'+'<a href="#" class="link" data-email="' + val + '">'+"Add as Friends"+'</a>'+'</td>').appendTo(tr);
}
```

Then you can use this to retrieve it:

```
$(".details").on("click", ".link", function() {
    var email = $(this).data("email");
    sendFriendRequest(email);
    $(this).text("Friend request sent");
});
```